# Automatically exclude certain emails from Gmail search?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I have a lot of emails from a certain person which I would like not to see in Gmail search results, and I'd prefer not to think about this person either.

However, I don't want to delete these emails permanently.

Is there a way I can exclude them from search results *by default*?

I know I could use operators like `-from:person@domain.com`, or add a label and exclude the label.

However, I'd really like to find a way to do this automatically, without having to think about the person each time I do a Gmail search.